# streaming write to gcs using apache beam per element

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Current beam pipeline is reading files as stream using `FileIO.matchAll().continuously()`. This returns PCollection .
I want to write these files back with the same names to another gcs bucket i.e each `PCollection` is one file `metadata/readableFile` which should be written back to another bucket after some processing. Is there any sink that i should use to achieve writing each `PCollection` item back to GCS or are there any ways to do it ?
Is it possible to create a window per element and then use some GCS sink IO to be able to do this.
When operating on a window (even if it has multiple elements) , does beam guarantees that either a window is fully processed or not processed at all , in other words are write operations to `GCS or bigquery` for a given window atomic and not partial in case of any failures ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you just need to copy files from one destination to another. Do you actually need Dataflow for this? I imagine you could use some combination of `gsutil`, `bq`, and Google Cloud Functions to achieve all of this.

Comment: yes almost that, i need to go through all events stored on those files and filter out some, mutate some , aggregate some , but within a file level , because that gives me idempotency , so that if i reprocess the same file i get same data . But if there are ways to achieve this by flattening files into streaming windowed events and then using the normal textio/avroio  then i would like to know those solution as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I can't think of any ways to achieve this. The requirement of file idempotency may be too complex to implement in Dataflow. A naive solution would be to process 1 file per Dataflow job, which is not unreasonable in my opinion.

Comment: oh that is definitely unreasonable. there are millions file generated every day ,we definitely cannot run million dataflow job just to process few megabytes in 1 file where  each file is just few throusand events. Running dataflow jobs per file is not a solution at all. not just dataflow , running any kind of binary per file to process one file per instantiation is not a solution. It is similar to saying i will have one server for one request

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply write a `DoFn<ReadableFile, Void>` that takes the file and copies it to the desired location using the `FileSystems` API? You don't need any "sink" to do that - and, in any case, this is what all "sinks" (`TextIO.write()`, `AvroIO.write()` etc.) are under the hood anyway: they are simply Beam transforms made of `ParDo`'s and `GroupByKey`'s.

Comment: that is what I am doing right now (and previous dataflow pipelines) . Wonder if there were any caveats or performance implications because i may be opening too many connections to gcs from each worker executing the DoFn on each  element.  I saw beam api provides dynamicdestination so thought there may be more idiomatic ways of handling this or some other sink .

Comment: Also is there a way to create windo per element and than trigger output per window ? Also can you answer about partial window processing ?

Comment: stuck job error : The network chosen for this job should have rules that open TCP ports 1-65535 for internal connection with other VMs. Without this, any pipeline with more than one worker that shuffles data will hang. The 'default' network is initially configured properly. Consider using it and/or ensure it hasn't been modified. Causes: Firewall rules associated with your network don't open TCP ports 1-65535 for Dataflow instances. If a firewall rule opens connection in these ports, ensure target tags aren't specified, or that the rule includes the tag 'dataflow'.

Comment: No caveats I can think of. If you need to create N files, there's no way to do it without doing N GCS upload calls - this is what your current code would do, and this is what the DynamicDestinations API (or better, FileIO.write()) would do too. The DD API would definitely be overkill here. I'm not sure I understand the question about window per element or about atomicity: are these questions still relevant in light of the above?